# Artifactory 6.0.3, cannot login to docker using Tomcat/repo

Tags: docker, authentication, artifactory

We're running artifactory 6.0.3 on-perm as a container (along with nginx and postgresql) as described in running artifactory as a docker instance.

I have set up the basic "docker" instance.

Locally on the same machine as the artifactory container:

```
# docker login localhost:8081
Username: test
Password: 
Login Succeeded
```

However, using the nginx port:

```
# export DOCKER_OPTS=" --insecure-registry docker-local.artifactory.company.com"
# docker login -u test --password-stdin artifactory.company.com
Error response from daemon: Get https://artifactory.company.com/v2/: unknown: Unsupported docker repository request for 'v2'
```

I also tried using ~/.docker/config.json with the auth information (base64) however it still giving me the same error.

artifactory.log shows:

```
2018-06-21 13:25:48,088 [http-nio-8081-exec-3] [ERROR] (o.a.a.d.r.DockerResource:425) - Unsupported docker repository request for 'v2'
```

access.log shows:

```
2018-06-21 13:25:48,089 [DENIED LOGIN]  for test/172.19.0.4
```

request.log shows:

```
20180625075813|1|REQUEST|172.19.0.2|_internal|GET|/api/system/configuration/reverseProxy/nginx|HTTP/1.1|404|0
20180625075823|1|REQUEST|172.19.0.2|_internal|GET|/api/system/configuration/reverseProxy/nginx|HTTP/1.1|404|0
20180625075823|1|REQUEST|10.15.9.4|non_authenticated_user|GET|/api/docker//v2/|HTTP/1.0|401|0
20180625075823|2|REQUEST|10.15.9.4|non_authenticated_user|GET|/api/docker/v2/token|HTTP/1.0|400|0
```

[ Note the _internal request for the reverseProxy line is repeating every 10 seconds, all 404  == I have confirmed that the "Http Settings" are set to "Repository Path" and "Internal Tomcat".]

EDIT 2:

Adding the access.log from nginx:

`ip = 10.15.53.21 user = "-" local_time = "27/Jun/2018:11:28:36 +0000" host = artifactory.company.com request = "GET /v2/ HTTP/1.1" status = 401 bytes = 87 upstream = "172.19.0.3:8081" upstream_time = 0.001 request_time = 0.001 referer = "-" UA = "docker/18.03.1-ce go/go1.9.5 git-commit/9ee9f40 kernel/3.10.0-862.3.3.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.03.1-ce \x5C(linux\x5C))"
ip = 10.15.53.121 user = "test" local_time = "27/Jun/2018:11:28:36 +0000" host = artifactory.company.com request = "GET /artifactory/api/docker//v2/token?account=test&client_id=docker&offline_token=true&service=artifactory.company.com%3A443 HTTP/1.1" status = 400 bytes = 122 upstream = "172.19.0.3:8081" upstream_time = 0.001 request_time = 0.001 referer = "-" UA = "docker/18.03.1-ce go/go1.9.5 git-commit/9ee9f40 kernel/3.10.0-862.3.3.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/18.03.1-ce \x5C(linux\x5C))"`

- 10.15.53.21 is the host itself, this is where the art-compose was run.
- 172.19.0.3 is the bridged docker network for the artifactory container.  nginx is 172.19.0.4.

Comment: several things, first there is no version 6.0.6 of artifactory, can you please fix that? 
Second, can you please check your repository configuration and see what is configured in the 'Docker Settings' --> 'API Version:'

Last but not least, what do you see in the request.log file in Artifactory?

Comment: It's artifactory 6.0.2... will update.  docker-local and remote are set to V2. ... I'll add the request log in-line.

Comment: From the request.log it seems that the request is reaching Artifactory with no authentication. Artifactory then returns 401, and getting no valid authentication from the client. At this point, I would check the Nginx logs to see if there is any error there or if the transmission is getting interrupted by the Nginx

Comment: Nothing in the error.log, I'll add the two entries from access.log in the question.  I have not made any changes to ngnix.  It's the auto-generated config from jfrog.

Comment: Updated to 6.0.3... still same issue.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the Artifactory version. It's not a bug in Artifactory and therefore the upgrade to 6.0.3 didn't help.As you can see in the access.log of nginx the Docker user is listed, however, when reaching to Artifactory there is no user used. It seems that it is related to a configuration issue on the reverse proxy side.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was a custom proxy configuration from @mcgurksean on github.

https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-docker-examples/issues/86#issuecomment-421031928

Additionally, you have to stop Artifactory from regenerating the nginx configuration file, answer from @jainishshah17 on github.

https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-docker-examples/issues/86#issuecomment-422849718